# Slow database operation Django filter

Tags: django, postgresql, performance, django-queryset, database-performance

I have to filter through a model that has around 24 mil. instances (records).
I need to filter them based on some name got from the url kwarg, I have something like this:
`Model.objects.filter(field__icontains=self.kwargs['kwarg']).values()`
on a view.

This is absolutely not efficient since the page is really slow and takes a lot of proccessing from the CPU. How can I solve this issue?

Thanks in advance for answers!

Comment: If using Postgres, look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/search/

Comment: Or use a search engine

Comment: It's slow even with the postgres search.
I've been looking at the elastic search engine with haystack. But I don't know how to use it in this situation.

Comment: That was not what you asked, but if you add to your OP what you have tried, I can help you with that. You will need something like `sqs = SearchQuerySet().filter(content=AutoQuery(value))`

Answer (score 0):

Create an index on the field. How effective that will be will vary somewhat by database engine, but it should help. Add `db_index=True` in the model definition of `field`. You can also take a look at [PostgreSQL full text indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/textsearch-tables.html#TEXTSEARCH-TABLES-INDEX).

Comment: I've already done that, it improved the performance, but it's still very slow.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an index on the field. But it has to be a specific index for it to be relevant to the `__icontains` filter.

A full analysis is here: https://medium.com/metakratos-studio/how-we-optimized-i-queries-and-found-inaccuracies-in-django-documentation-d921a44d8bc4

The `db_index=True` in the model definition creates a B-Tree index which  can handle equality and range queries. This is useful only with the `__exact` filer in django (the = operator in SQL). It won't be used even with the `__iexact` filter because this filter uses the SQL operation UPPER on the data before the = operator in SQL. This needs a custom index or with Django 3.2+ the OpClass expression.

For the `__contains` filter, the LIKE operator is used in the SQL and requires the Postgres Trigram extension for full-text search. Particularly Gin indexes seems to work the best.

The `__icontains` filter could use a Gin index but like the `__iexact` filer, it also uses an UPPER SQL operation on the data before the LIKE operator. So it needs a needs a custom Gin index or with Django 3.2+ the `OpClass` expression.

So for this latter, I had to use this in the model:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.indexes import GinIndex, OpClass

  class Meta:
      indexes = [
          GinIndex(fields=['name'], name='name_gin_index',
opclasses=['gin_trgm_ops'])
      ]
```

You also need to activate the Trigram extension in your migrations by adding `TrigramExtension()`  (`from django.contrib.postgres.operations import TrigramExtension`) to the list of migrations operation before the creation of the index